# TFS Gated checkin error: No shelved changes for $/ or you do not have permissions to access them. Why am I getting this error?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfs-2015

We recently upgraded to TFS 2015 and I've been using XAML builds for my gated checkins since some of the developers are still using VS 2012 and the XAML builds allow them to view the build progress locally. So I just tried to set up my first TFS 2015 gated checkin and it fails. Here's my build defintion:

[image: Build Definition 1]

[image: Build Definition 2]

[image: Build Definition 3]

And here's the error that I'm getting. Any ideas why? I use a very similar build definition for my regular builds and they work fine (with some additional steps to copy the build to a drop location).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be caused by the Project Collection Build Service does not have the permission to access the code repository. Please check it via the steps below:

1. Open TFS Web Portal and navigate to "Code" tab.
2. Click "..." button at the root level or the folder you mapped in your build definition.
3. Select "Security..." option.
4. Check if "Project Collection Build Service" is listed in the security settings. If not, add it by clicking "Add..." button.
5. Check the permission of "Project Collection Build Service" and make sure it has "Read" permission to access to the code.
   [image]

Comment: Hi Eddie. Thanks, When I follow your steps I see Project Collection Build Service (Team Foundation) at the bottom left side. It has Inherited Allow as the permission. That looks good - right?

Comment: Project Collection Build Service was missing from the project that was having the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the log info, seems changes are not included. Try to set the **Clean** option from false to true.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vs/alm/build/define/repository#GitHubOtheroptions):

> •Set this to false if you want to define an incremental build to
>   improve performance.

And you could also create an empty build definition for the gated-check in to narrow down the issue to see if it's related to your build definition or your account/ your build agent.

Comment: Nope Patrick - that doesn't help. I get the same error. I tried checking Clean on the Build tab and setting the Clean dropdown to true on the Repository tab and even added a variable called Build.Clean and set it's value to source and none of the three helped. (I have no idea why I would need to set Clean in three different places - can you explain that please?

Comment: And I got one gated build working (on a different branch) and tried cloning it and then just making the needed changes to have it point to the desired branch and I still  get the same error.

Comment: If this works on another branch but not work on the desired one. Seems to be a permission issue. Please double check if your build service account  have enough permission on that branch. Just right click the branch and select  security in VS source control explorer. Detail steps please refer below eddie's answer.

Comment: If all above is not worked, try to update your build agent to latest version or create a new build agent.